# How do I remote write metrics to Google Managed Prometheus?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, netdata, google-managed-prometheus

I am trying to push metrics collected by a Netdata container acting as a parent in a GKE cluster into Google Managed Prometheus. I am following the netdata docs here: https://learn.netdata.cloud/docs/exporting/prometheus-remote-write
and I realized that I don't know how to write metrics to GMP. Does anyone know what the endpoint of GMP actually is, and if it even supports the Remote Write protocol?

Thanks!

Comment: Currently remote write is not supported and it’s under implementation. In Prometheus terms, an endpoint you can scrape is called an instance, usually corresponding to a single process. A collection of instances with the same purpose, a process replicated for scalability or reliability for example, is called a job.

Comment: You can refer to this document on [Job and instances](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/jobs_instances/#:~:text=In%20Prometheus%20terms%2C%20an%20endpoint,example%2C%20is%20called%20a%20job.) and [Google Cloud Managed service for prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus) for more details. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Please let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries.

Comment: Can I convert the above comment as a solution to have greater visibility to community members ? Looking forward for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

It's not implemented yet, thanks @fariya!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).